# Kivy - creating a scalable ScrollView

Tags: python, scrollview, kivy

I'm trying to create a scrollview where I select an option via a dropdown menu and then press the + button to add two labels in a row to the scrollview. This is my code so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class CaloriesScreen(Screen):
    pass

class theScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

theScreenManager:
    CaloriesScreen:

<CaloriesScreen>:
    name: 'calories'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .3
            Button:
                text: '<'
                size_hint: .1, 1
                font_size: 75
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                on_release: app.root.current = 'main' 

            Label:
                text: 'Calories'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            Widget:
                size_hint: .1, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .4
            spacing: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: 'Recipes'
                font_size: 30
                color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1


            Button:
                id: btn
                text: 'Select a recipe...'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: dropdown.open(self)
                height: '48dp'
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 0.75}
                size_hint: .8, .5

            DropDown:

                id: dropdown
                on_parent: self.dismiss()
                on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])


                Button:
                    text: 'Simple Cheese Omelette'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('First Item')

                Button:
                    text: 'Burger'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('Second Item')

                Button:
                    text: 'Tomato and Caper Linguine'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('Third Item')


            Button:
                text: '+'
                font_size: 30
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 0.65}
                size_hint: .1, .3
                #on_release:
            Widget:
                size_hint: .02, 1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, .2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0.18, .5, .92
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text:'Food'
                color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            Label:
                text:'Calories'
                color: (1, 1, 1, 1)

        ScrollView:
            scroll_timeout: 250
            scroll_distance: 20
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                cols: 2
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10
                Label:
                    text:'Food'
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                Label:
                    text:'Calories'
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)


''')

class temprecipeapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temprecipeapp().run()
```

The food and calories labels in white on the scrollview are examples. Ideally they would float to the top and then I would be able to select a new option from the dropdown and add more to the queue. How would I go about this? Currently if I add lots of labels that stack in the scrollview the scroll does not enable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an item to fit two columns, `food` and `calories` it'll be probably the best to "copy" the behavior from the table headers i.e. `Food` and `Calories` and create a separate container for them as a `FoodItem`, which is just a `BoxLayout`.

That `FoodItem` will have two `StringProperties`:

- food
- calories

and you can access them in kv by `root.food`, `root.calories`.

Now to create such an item in kv directly and place it into the `ScrollView`, you'll need [`Factory`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html), which isn't available by default, therefore import. With that you can do basically this:

```
Factory.MyWidget()
```

and it'll create an instance of your widget, which you need to pass to your `GridLayout`'s `add_widget` method.

**Edits in code:**

```
...
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

...
root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory  # <- import Factory

...
            DropDown:

                id: dropdown
#                on_parent: self.dismiss()  <- don't do this
                on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])


                Button:
                    text: 'Simple Cheese Omelette'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('First Item')

                Button:
                    text: 'Burger'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('Second Item')

                Button:
                    text: 'Tomato and Caper Linguine'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: '48dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('Third Item')


            Button:
                text: '+'
                font_size: 30
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: 0.18, .5, .92, 1
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 0.65}
                size_hint: .1, .3
                on_release: grid.add_widget(Factory.FoodItem(food=btn.text, calories='10'))  <- add a new item

...
        ScrollView:
            scroll_timeout: 250
            scroll_distance: 20
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                cols: 1  <- change cols
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height  <- make the layout resize itself
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

<FoodItem>:
    size_hint_y: None 
    height: 20  <- set a size for the item
    Label:
        text: root.food
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
    Label:
        text: root.calories
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
''')

class FoodItem(BoxLayout):
    food = StringProperty('')
    calories = StringProperty('')

...
```

Also consider using [`Spinner`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html) instead of a pure `Dropdown` as it makes the things easier (and you'll avoid `on_parent` behavior).